# Angular: Setting a date field by dropdown menu's selection

Tags: angular, typescript, primeng, angular13

Let's say I have a dropdown menu, with the following options: "WORK", "RELEASE", "OPEN" and a second field, a calendar, which is initially an empty field. By setting the dropdown menu to "RELEASE" it should trigger the calendar field, setting it to today's date. The template looks like this (form.component.html):

```
<form [formGroup]="form">
    <div class="flex">
        <div class="col-3">
            <div class="flex flex-row align-items-center">
                <label class="col-6">Status</label>
                <p-dropdown
                    [options]="workStatus"
                    [showClear]="true"
                    formControlName="workingStatus"
                    class="col-6">
                </p-dropdown>
            </div>
            <div class="flex flex-row align-items-center">
                <label class="col-6">Date</label>
                <p-calendar formControlName="getWorkDate"
                            dateFormat="dd-mm-yyyy"
                            dataType="localdate"
                            appendTo="body"
                            class="col-6">
                </p-calendar>
```

In order to get today's date I have written the following function in the form.component.ts:

```js
selectTodaysDate(DateToday: number[]) {
    const todayDate = new Date().getDate();
    this.form.patchValue({getWorkDate: DateToday.find(today => today == todayDate)});
}
```

but I don't know how to trigger the dropdown menu. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can work with `onchange` event. Refer to the table under the [Events](https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/dropdown) section.

```
<p-dropdown
    [options]="workStatus"
    [showClear]="true"
    formControlName="workingStatus"
    (onChange)="onDropdownChange($event.value)"
    class="col-6"
    >
</p-dropdown>
```

```js
onDropdownChange(value) {
  if (value == 'RELEASE')
    this.form.controls["getWorkDate"].setValue(new Date());
}
```

[Sample Demo on StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/primeng-dropdown-demo-i6fauw?file=src/app/app.component.html)

---

Side note:

The dateFormat should be `dd-mm-yy` instead of `dd-mm-yyyy` for `<p-calendar>`. Refer to [DateFormat](https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/calendar) section.

Answer (score 1):

You can bind change event with dropdown like this and based on your response you can make it possible.

Example

**HTML** :

```
<p-dropdown  
[options]="workStatus"
[showClear]="true"
formControlName="workingStatus"
class="col-6"  
(onChange)="onChange($event)">
</p-dropdown>
```

In the **TS** file you can put conditions based on that you can enable your calendar.

```
onChange(event) {
    console.log('event :' + event);
    console.log(event.value);
    if(event.value === "RELEASE"){
     this.selectTodaysDate(params); // Function call
   // or you can simply patch form value here like this
     const todayDate = new Date().getDate();
     this.form.patchValue({getWorkDate: DateToday.find(today => today == todayDate)});
   }
}
```

Function which have already created.

```
selectTodaysDate(DateToday: number[]) {
        const todayDate = new Date().getDate();
        this.form.patchValue({getWorkDate: DateToday.find(today => today == todayDate)});
    }
```